# Java connect to FTP server and download files with java default libraries

Tags: java, ftp

I need to connect to an FTP server and browse all files without using any libraries like apache.commons because I don't have the option to get these libraries at the moment.

I tried using a simple URL connection:

```
URL url = new URL("username:password@ip/folder/");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

String line;

while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

reader.close();
```

When I don't include the `/folder/` it works, but it prints me many things that I can't even see in the home location of the FTP server, I don't know if it gives me the files or other data.

But when I do include `/folder/` i get error  `CWD /folder/:550 failed to change directory`

and I cannot change the directoy's permissions, its read-only and thats what I need.

What is wrong with it? Is it possible to do with just java's default libraries?

Comment: check out this link http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/using-urlconnection-to-list-files-and-directories-on-ftp-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use an FTP URL:

```
URL url = new URL("ftp:username:password@ip/folder/");
```

assuming `username` and `password` are substituted with their correct values.

Second, if you have FTP access to `folder` it will deliver you a directory listing in some format. If you don't, you need to study the exception message you get. If you omit `/folder` it will give you a listing of whatever the FTP server's default root directory is for that `username`. The code 550 means either an access problem or that the directory doesn't exist.